# Making a lense using an array?

Tags: waves, refraction, diffraction, lenses, huygens-principle

Would it be possible to build a lense out of array elements with a higher refractive index inter spaced with void elements eg a matrix of glass with air.

[image]

I imagine that the spacing would have to be considerably smaller than the wavelength

Would the Refractive index be an average of the refractive indices of the elements the wave passes thru ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually a very insightful question!  Yes, it is possible.  If the spacing is less than a half wavelength, then the effective refractive index is the average of the refractive indices.

Something not very distant conceptually from what you propose is a diffractive lens or Fresnel zone plate. [http://zoneplate.lbl.gov/theory]

And another technology that borders on what you propose is a metamaterial lens: [https://www.laserfocusworld.com/articles/2016/06/diffraction-limited-metalenses-operate-at-visible-wavelengths.html]